# Display uMap map background at higher zoom levels?

Tags: openstreetmap, umap

## Context

A really quick question as I'm trying to set up a map for showing GIS capabilities to beginners using [uMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/UMap).

If I personalize the zoom level by increasing the highest value from 20 (which is the default maximum initial value) to 24, the map background is no more displayed when I actually zoom beyond 20 (the map background simply becomes gray):

[image: uMap screenshot]

## Question

Is there something I can do to display the map background while zooming to closer zoom levels (greater than 20)?

Comment: Each additional zoom level leads to an increase in the resource required for running a (raster) tile server. That's why usual tile servers only contain raster tiles for zoom levels up to 18, sometimes up to 20. If you need higher zoom levels consider [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) your own tiles or switch to vector tiles.

Comment: I didn't mentioned it, but indeed, if adding vector tiles to uMap is possible, it would be really great.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if this is possible at the moment :(

Comment: Related question at https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/75120/displaying-map-beyond-zoom-level-19

Answer (score 1):

tile.openstreetmap.fr have a limit to 20 zoom level. I don't see an option that you can zoom (digital) more level. If you need it, you can use another tile.server like `https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png` https://github.com/CartoDB/basemap-styles

Comment: Look this example https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/milano-linee-metropolitana_382222

Comment: That's cool, but the most important objects for my project are trees, and they are not present on this map! :')

Comment: I saw that `Thunderforest.Landscape` have limit zoom to 22 and here you can see the trees https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=Thunderforest.Landscape

Comment: Also `CyclOSM` https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=CyclOSM

Comment: Too `HikeBike.HikeBike` https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=HikeBike.HikeBike